# Trying to add up total cost of double array list based on index of string arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have an array list of recurring strings `deploy`, and an array list of those strings with no duplicates `singDeploy`. I also have an array list of doubles `rate` that have the same index as `deploy`. I'm trying to add up all the rates for each deploy string and store them in `totCost` that match up to `singDeploy` index however my for loop is giving me an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Not too sure why and still don't fully know if my loop gets that job done.

```
 List<String> deploy = new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> singDeploy = new ArrayList<>();
 List<Double> totCost = new ArrayList<>();
 List<Double> rate = new ArrayList<>();
  singDeploy.addAll(Arrays.asList("Green Cow", "Green Elephant", "Green Rhinocerous", "Purple Cow", "Yellow Cat", "Red Sloth"));

  deploy.addAll(Arrays.asList("Green Cow", "Green Cow", "Green Elephant", "Green Cow", "Green Cow", "Green Rhinocerous", "Purple Cow", "Yellow Cat", "Red Sloth", "Green Cow", "Purple Cow", "Green Cow", "Red Sloth", "Yellow Cat", "Green Rhinocerous", "Purple Cow"));

  rate.addAll(Arrays.asList(0.553683754016, 1.02150872447, 0.134625067987, 1.98664453833, 0.861269450714, 0.36946659851, 0.909230205525, 0.00248039618935, 0.160619970732, 0.545320579333, 0.0709241158945, 3.96782782573E-6, 0.849530002338, 1.29965105158, 6.72974424027E-6, 4.51463564725E-6));


 for(int i=0;i<singDeploy.size();i++) {
    for(int j=0;i<deploy.size();j++) {
    if(singDeploy.get(i)==deploy.get(j)) {
        double temp=totCost.get(i);
        System.out.println(temp);
        totCost.add(temp+=rate.get(j));
    }
     else {
        j++;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Can you please provide us the full stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things,

`for(int j=0;j <deploy.size();j++) { // Use j`,

`totCost.get(j); // Use j again,`

`singDeploy.get(i).equals(deploy.get(j)) // Use equals`

Or try this,

```
for(int i=0;i < singDeploy.size() ;i++) {
             Double curCost = 0.0;
             String currDeploy = singDeploy.get(i);
             for(int j=0;j<deploy.size();j++) {
                 if(deploy.get(j).equals(currDeploy))
                     curCost += rate.get(j);
             }
             totCost.add(curCost);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`double temp=totCost.get(i);`

You are trying to access an element in totCost which does not have an element inside.
That could be the reason for IndexOutOfBound.

Answer (score 0):

At line `for(int j=0;i<deploy.size();j++) {`, you should put j instead of i

```
for(int j=0;j<deploy.size();j++) {
```

It is going for infinite loop in your current code. Also, as Bhargav mentioned, you are trying to access the element i.e.

```
double temp=totCost.get(i);
```

which doesn't have any element inside.